# Increasing number of OMP threads changes output value

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I attach a code which when parallelised using OMP gives different outputs. 
This is not meant to happen.

I believe i've covered the usual usual pitfalls vis-a-vis 'private' variables and 'reduction' clauses.

I attach the relevant function from the global code. Any wisdom is gratefully received.

EDIT* I suspect the problem lies in my arma::cross product taken of the column vectors taken from the ith iteration of MatIplusIplus and the jth itheration of MatPtJplusJplus ? *

```
double calcul( arma::mat MatPt, int iS, int THREADS){ 

int i,j, count = 1;
double Wr = 0 , Omega;

arma::mat MatJplusIplus ( 3 , iS ) ;
arma::mat MatJI ( 3 , iS ) ;
arma::mat MatJplusI ( 3 , iS ) ;
arma::mat MatJIplus ( 3 , iS ) ;

arma::mat MatIplusI ( 3 , iS ) ;
arma::mat MatJplusJ ( 3 , iS ) ;

#pragma omp parallel for private(j) reduction(+: Wr) reduction(*: Omega)
for( i = 0 ; i < iS- (3) ; i++ ){//rethink boundaries.

    MatIplusI ( 0 , i ) = MatPt (0, i+1) - MatPt (0, i) ;
    MatIplusI ( 1 , i ) = MatPt (1, i+1) - MatPt (1, i) ;
    MatIplusI ( 2 , i ) = MatPt (2, i+1) - MatPt (2, i) ;

    for( j= i+2 ; j < iS-(1) ; j++ ){

        MatJIplus  ( 0, j ) = MatPt (0, j) - MatPt (0, i+1) ;
        MatJIplus  ( 1, j ) = MatPt (1, j) - MatPt (1, i+1) ;
        MatJIplus  ( 2, j ) = MatPt (2, j) - MatPt (2, i+1) ;

        MatJplusIplus  ( 0, j ) = MatPt (0, j+1) - MatPt (0, i+1) ;
        MatJplusIplus  ( 1, j ) = MatPt (1, j+1) - MatPt (1, i+1) ;
        MatJplusIplus  ( 2, j ) = MatPt (2, j+1) - MatPt (2, i+1) ;

        MatJI  ( 0, j ) = MatPt (0, j) - MatPt (0, i) ;
        MatJI  ( 1, j ) = MatPt (1, j) - MatPt (1, i) ;
        MatJI  ( 2, j ) = MatPt (2, j) - MatPt (2, i) ;

        MatJplusI  ( 0, j ) = MatPt (0, j+1) - MatPt (0, i) ;
        MatJplusI  ( 1, j ) = MatPt (1, j+1) - MatPt (1, i) ;
        MatJplusI  ( 2, j ) = MatPt (2, j+1) - MatPt (2, i) ;

        arma::vec n1 = arma::cross( MatJI.col(j) , MatJplusI.col(j) ) ;
        arma::vec n2 = arma::cross( MatJplusI.col(j) , MatJplusIplus.col(j) ) ;
        arma::vec n3 = arma::cross( MatJplusIplus.col(j) , MatJIplus.col(j) ) ;
        arma::vec n4 = arma::cross( MatJIplus.col(j) , MatJI.col(j) ) ;

       //normalise vectors
        arma::vec N1 =  normalise(n1) ;
        arma::vec N2 =  normalise(n2) ;
        arma::vec N3 =  normalise(n3) ;
        arma::vec N4 =  normalise(n4) ;

        //take dot product
        const double ndot1 = arma:: dot ( N1 , N2 ) ;
        const double ndot2 = arma:: dot ( N2 , N3 ) ;
        const double ndot3 = arma:: dot ( N3 , N4 ) ;
        const double ndot4 = arma:: dot ( N4 , N1 ) ;

        Omega = asin(ndot1) + asin(ndot2) + asin(ndot3) + asin(ndot4) ;

        MatJplusJ( 0 , j ) = MatPt (0, j+1) - MatPt (0, j) ;
        MatJplusJ ( 1 , j ) = MatPt (1, j+1) - MatPt (1, j) ;
        MatJplusJ ( 2 , j ) = MatPt (2, j+1) - MatPt (2, j) ;

        arma::vec v = arma::cross( MatJplusJ.col(j) , MatIplusI.col(i) );

        const double wij = arma:: dot(v, MatJI.col(j) ) ;

        if (wij < 0){

             Omega *= -1/ ( 4* pi ) ;

        }

        else{

            Omega *= 1/ ( 4* pi ) ;

        }

        if (Omega != Omega){//incase something goes wrong, ignore !

            Omega = 0 ;

        }

        Wr += Omega ;

        //cout << i << " " << j << endl ;

       //PrivEnd

    }

}

Wr *= 2 ;


return Wr ;
```

}

Many thanks

Comment: What's the point of making `Omega` a reduction if it is not used after the parallel section? What you want is `private(Omega)`

Comment: If the result changes depending on the number of threads, it smells like a data-race.

Comment: Omega is set to private (thanks simpl01 !)

Comment: data-race wise.. the reduction clause was meant to deal with that, also played with 'critical' and 'atomic' directives, but with no joy. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many race conditions on all matrix accesses on `j`. For example `MatJIplus  ( 0, j ) = ...` will be set concurrently by different iterations of the outer loop.

Since these data structures are indirect, you cannot just declare them as private, you must construct them in the worker threads themselves. Since you only use the parts of the matrices that are written within each loop body, you could declare them inside the loop body. However, to avoid reallocating those again and again in every loop, you can split the `parallel for` as such:

```
arma::mat MatIplusI ( 3 , iS ) ;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Matrices will be implicitly private and correctly constructed locally for each thread.
    arma::mat MatJplusIplus ( 3 , iS ) ;
    arma::mat MatJI ( 3 , iS ) ;
    arma::mat MatJplusI ( 3 , iS ) ;
    arma::mat MatJIplus ( 3 , iS ) ;
    arma::mat MatJplusJ ( 3 , iS ) ;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(j) reduction(+: Wr) private(Omega)
    {
        for( i = 0 ; i < iS- (3) ; i++ )
```

Note that reduction on `Omega` makes absolutely no sense, it should be private instead.

Also it makes little sense to allocate memory for the full matrices, when you only use columns of them within each iteration. Just make a suitable private datastructure to hold the `column(i/j)` contents in the first place.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered the Question, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.